# Prove inequality for all complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Prove following inequality for all complex numbers:
$
\lvert z\rvert \le \lvert z \rvert ^2 + \lvert z-1 \rvert
$

It is obvious for $\lvert z\rvert \gt 1 $ but what about the rest ? 
 
Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It is also obvious for $|z|=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Write the inequality as $|z| (1 - |z|) \le |z-1|$.  If $|z| \le 1$, 
$|z| (1-|z|) \le 1 - |z|$.

Answer (score 1):

Try the triangle inequality
$$
|z| = |z-z^2+z^2| \le |z-z^2|+|z^2|=|z||z-1|+|z^2|\le|z-1|+|z^2|
$$
when $|z|\le1$.

Note also, $|z^2|=|z|^2$.